# How to retry requests in Angular 17 functional interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm searching for about two days and can't find out a working solution, and can't figure out a way to make this to work.

I've used Angular for a while, but when Angular was in version 12. Now, I'm trying to "update" myself with new Angular, but I'm stuck on writing an interceptor for API calls.

I need an interceptor that appends the Authorization header (a Bearer JWT token) to all requests, and, if the request results in a 401 error, or the token is expired by validating the token itself (both are the same - if the token is expired and used, my backend returns a 401 error), call my `AuthService.refreshToken()` to get a new token, then retry the initial request with the new token.

My current interceptor code looks like this:

```js
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { ILoginResponse } from '../interfaces/iloginresponse';
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';

export const apiInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
    var service = inject(AuthService);
    var request = req.clone();
    
    let token: string|null = sessionStorage.getItem("access_token");
    if(token !== null){
        let tokenData = jwtDecode(token);
        if(tokenData.exp! < Date.now()/1000 && !isRefreshing){
            service.refreshToken().subscribe((data) => {
                isRefreshing = false;
                let loginData = data as ILoginResponse;
                token = loginData.access_token;

                sessionStorage.setItem("access_token", token);

                request = req.clone({
                    headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)
                });

                return next(request);
            });
        }

        request = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)
        });
    }

    return next(request);
};
```

The problem is: when an API call returns 401, it calls the `refreshToken()` method from my `AuthService`, but doesn't retry the request. I'm sure the `return next(request)` inside the `subscribe()` from the `refreshToken()` is returning *to the subscribe*, instead to the "main" function. But I don't know how to properly do this.

I've tried adding a `return` statement on the `service.refreshToken().subscribe(..)` method, but it crashes the entire code due to TS validations.

So, can someone help me? I need to know how to properly retry a request directly from the interceptor, in the context of Angular 15+ functional interceptors (I've read that functional interceptors were introduced on Angular 15).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I don't know if the best approach, but did you try to use **await** at this case?
[firstValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom)

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño yes, I've also tried using async/await, but the main function (in this case, the apiInterceptor) must not be an async method. When using async/await, it gaves me TS validation errors.